# Testing the Capacity of a modem

Tags: wifi

I want to determine the capacity of a modem. I need to generate some clients for a modem and increase the number of them to test the capacity of the modem ([TR-398 Standard- Capacity Test](https://www.smallnetbuilder.com/wireless/wireless-features/33219-introduction-to-the-tr-398-wi-fi-performance-test?start=2)). I want to know how I can simulate these users with a single Wifi interface.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to know how I can simulate these users with a single Wifi interface.

You can't. Even if the single Wifi interface offers multiple virtual STA interfaces, then you are measuring *also* the capacity restrictions imposed by multiplexing those interfaces in your single Wifi interface.

So you need to buy 16 2x2 STA Wifi interfaces. Or you rely on the numbers someone has measured who bought those.

---

From the test description:

> The Multiple Association / Disassociation Stability (6.4.2) test's goal is to see how well throughput on multiple STAs is maintained while STAs connect and disconnect. 16 2x2 vSTAs are first associated, with 8 of the 16 running 4 Mbps of UDP traffic in 2.4 GHz or 8 Mbps in 5 GHz. Traffic runs for 30 seconds, then the 8 vSTAs that are not running traffic are disassociated. After 30 seconds, the 8 vSTAs are reassociated and the test ends about 10 seconds later. Throughput and packet loss are measured for each vSTA throughout the test.

So whatever you use for the STAs, it must be able to sustain 4 Mbps on 2.4 GHz or 8 Mbps on 5 GHz. A random microcontroller may or may not be able to achieve this, it depends on the microcontroller, and how the Wifi hardware is connected to it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can I use 32 wifi modules and connect them to microcontrollers to implement this test (capacity of multi user in  a Wifi equipment)?

Comment: Thank you for your consideration. Is not the Wifi module important in this procedure? I think the Wifi module should sustain  4 Mbps on 2.4 GHz or 8 Mbps on 5 GHz too. About the microcontroller, I want to use STM32 H7 Microcontroller which is connect to the Wifi modules with SPI interface